# How to edit script in advanced formatting of ArcGIS Dashboard to show data as list?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, dashboard

So the code sent hasnt changed the formatting of the "Types of Facilities" format.[image]I have a listing of facilities seperated by a "**;**" in one cell in my attribute table. Since uploading my feature layer to AGOL Dashboard I would like to format my facilities so it shows as a list rather than just seperated by ; and looking like a sentence.

Below is the code and image for reference:

return {
textColor: '',
backgroundColor: '',
separatorColor:'#ffffff',
selectionColor: '',
selectionTextColor: '',
// attributes: {
// attribute1: '',
// attribute2: ''
// }

[image: Types of Facilities]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arcade to create the list and insert it into your control

```js
var facilities = $datapoint["facilities"]; //use the proper field for this
var facilitiesList = Concatenate(Split(facilities, '; '), '\n');

return { 
  textColor: '', 
  backgroundColor: '', 
  separatorColor:'#ffffff', 
  selectionColor: '', 
  selectionTextColor: '',
  middleText: facilitiesList, 
  // attributes: { 
     // attribute1: '', 
    // attribute2: '' 
 // }
```

Comment: I added the actual column name which was "HF_Number_Type" but the code is still not working. I feel like its almost there. Appreciate all the help.



var facilities = $datapoint["HF_Number_Type"]; //use the proper field for this
var facilitiesList = Concatenate(Split(facilities, '; '), '\n');

return { 
  textColor: '', 
  backgroundColor: '', 
  separatorColor:'#ffffff', 
  selectionColor: '', 
  selectionTextColor: '',
  middleText: facilitiesList, 
  // attributes: { 
     // attribute1: '', 
    // attribute2: '' 
}

Comment: When you expand the Arcade script window and test it, do you get any error messages? Can you use the console to show what the facilities variable contains?

Comment: Yes I had tested it i the Arcade script window but nothing shows.

Comment: var facilities = $datapoint["HF_Number_Type"]; //use the proper field for this
var facilitiesList = Concatenate(Split(facilities, '; '),'\n');

return { 
  textColor: '', 
  backgroundColor: '', 
  separatorColor:'#ffffff', 
  selectionColor: '', 
  selectionTextColor: '',
  middleText: facilitiesList, 
  // attributes: { 
     // attribute1: '', 
    // attribute2: '' 
 }